# XCode 4 - what is the "i" symbol

Tags: xcode4

I know an "m" symbol next to a file is modified etc.

Now I'm seeing an "i" symbol next to a ".a" file that I got from an external library.
What does that symbol mean?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out, it is the "ignore" symbol.